# two surf plots same graph

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, projection

I have the next script,

```
 R  = 0:0.1:1;
 z  = cos(-R);          
 zz  = sin(-R);        
 th = 0:pi/20:2*pi;
 X  = bsxfun(@times,R',cos(th));
 Y  = bsxfun(@times,R',sin(th));
 Z  = repmat(z',1,length(th));
 ZZ  = repmat(zz',1,length(th));
 surf(X,Y,Z)
 surf(X,Y,ZZ)
 box
 hold on
 surf(X*0 + 1,Y,Z) 
 surf(X*0 - 1,Y,ZZ)
```

I would like to have the plot result of the `z` and `zz` function, having different transparency.

The code is working using only the `z` function, but I can't make it to work `z` with `zz`; can't have surf plot `z` with `zz`. Any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to put the "hold on" right after the first surf plot. 
You can adjust the transparency with the "facealpha" parameter.

Comment: I done that. But it is not what I want it.If you run the script without zz(ZZ... ) only for z, you will see a surf plot. There is another one only with zz. I need both to be on the same box! When I do what you said the plot is wrong, like divide the z axis in two areas. I do not wish that.

Comment: What do you mean? Your ZZ data are all negative, and Z are all positive. So I assume there's something wrong with your calculation of Z. Would it help to shift ZZ by adding +1 or multiplying by -1?

Comment: you have right! ... i did notice that. but still the transparency is not working. If I have alpha(0.8) for the first plot, and the second (0.1), both will be 0.1.

Comment: Does surf(X,Y,ZZ,"Facealpha",0.1) within the call to the second "surf" work?

Comment: I will appreciate if you know any link, which could show how to plot the  surf(X*0 + 1,Y,Z) ( in the side wall ) as a 2Dplot z-R

Comment: Can you create a new vector R=sqrt(X.^2*y^2), and plot R vs. Z? Another option would be to plot surf(X*0+1,Y,Z) and adjust the view to "view(2)" or "view([0 90])". The documentation should have a good explanation for "view".